# Rational fixed points?

Tags: rational-numbers, fixed-points

What class of functions admits a rational fixed point?

I know that Brouwer's or Kakutani theorems give us existence of fixed point theorems for certain functions. I further need to know which class of functions necessarily admits a rational fixed point?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with a class of functions? I can take an arbitrary function $f$ and get $g(x) = xf(x)$ which admits fixed point $g(0) = 0$.

Comment: I mean in the way Brouwer says, 'A continuous function on a compact convex set to itself always possess a fixed point'.
I need a characterization of such flavor, this as is obviously does not work.

You could have made such a example function g in case for Brouwer's theorem as well.